# Colouring Gaussian integers according to a numeral system based on powers of $-1+i$

Tags: nt.number-theory

It is easy to check that every Gaussian integer can be written uniquely as a finite sum of the form $\sum_{n\geq 0}\epsilon_n(-1+i)^n$ for ‘digits’ $\epsilon_n$ in $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$.

The sequence $\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1,\dotsc$
can be computed by the algorithm:

```
Input: z in $\mathbb Z[i]$.

iterate until  z=0:

t=Re(z)+Im(z) modulo 2 (value taken in $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$)

print(t) and replace z by (z-t)/(-1+i):

enditerate
```

Changing the above pseudocode slightly by stopping (for non-zero $z$
in $\mathbb Z[i]$) when $z$ is among the fourth-roots of unity $\lbrace \pm 1,\pm i\rbrace$ and coloring the initial Gaussian integer with yellow, green, red, blue if the algorithm stops with $1$, $-1$, $i$, $-i$ yields the following picture (for Gaussian integers with real and imaginary values in $\lbrace -100,100\rbrace$):

[image: Image of "stopping 4th root"]

Striking features (experimentally on the picture):

The picture is fractal in nature (this is more or less obvious from the definition, the picture should be approximately invariant (perhaps up to a colour permutation) under multiplication by $-1+i$).

‘Connected components’ (defined in the obvious way) are bounded
except for green  (corresponding to $-1$ if I am not mistaken) where there seem to be three infinite components meeting
at the origin.

There is a sort of curious symmetry of order $3$ (up to a dilatation).

*Are there any nice explanations of these features?*

**Remark**: Changing the picture algorithm slightly by dividing by
$(1+i)$ instead of $(-1+i)$ leads to a sort of dual picture:

[image: Picture of "stopping 4th roots" for the changed algorithm]

Colours have a unique ‘connected component’ except for red (corresponding to $i$) which has infinitely many.

Observe that powers of $(1+i)$ yield a slightly less satisfying numeral system: One has to accept leading coefficients in $\lbrace 1,i\rbrace$ in order to get finite sums for all Gaussian integers.

**Added elementary explanation and analogue for Eisenstein integers**:

$b=-1+i$ defines a nice numeral system, see for example the reference
mentionned in the comment of Alison Miller below.
Every Gaussian integer can be written uniquely as a finite sum of distinct
natural powers of $b$. Colouring a non-zero
Gaussian integer $z$ with the first unit-root hit during the computation of '$b$-digits' (in $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace\}$) of $z$ seems like a natural idea
and the result depends of course only on the leading digits of the '$b$-expansion' of $z$. More precisely, writing $(\epsilon_n\ldots \epsilon_0)_b$ for the
$b$-expansion of $\sum_{j=0}^n\epsilon_j(-1+i)^j$, we have
\begin{align*}
  1&=1_b,\\
  i&=11_b,\\-i&=111_b,\\
  -1&=11101_b.
\end{align*}
The colour of the non-zero Gaussian integer encoded by
$w=(\epsilon_n\ldots \epsilon_0)_b$ is therefore the colour of $1$
if $w=1$ or $w=10*$ (where $*$ represents an arbitrary finite word
with letters $0$ and $1$).

The colour of $w$ is the colour of $i$ if $w=11$ or $w=110*$.

The colour of $w$ is the colour of $-i$ if $w=111$ or $w=1111*$
or $w=11100*$.

The colour of $w$ is the colour of $-1$ in the remaining cases, i.e.
if $w=11101*$.

Colours can therefore be computed by a finite state automaton
defining a $2$-automatic sequence (after interpreting
a $b$-expansion $w\in\{0,1\}^*$ as a binary digit).

There is a similar phenomenon for Eisenstein integers $\mathbb Z[(1+i\sqrt{3})/2]$: A numeral basis with digits in $\{0,1,2\}$ (giving rise to a bijection
between Eisenstein integers and $\mathbb N$ by considering ternary expansions)
is given by $b=(-3+i\sqrt{3})/2$. Unit-roots have the following $b$-expansions
with digits in $\{0,1,2\}$:
\begin{align*}
  1&=1_b,\\
  (1+i\sqrt{3})/2&=12_b,\\
  (-1+i\sqrt{3})/2&=11_b,\\
  (-1-i\sqrt{3})/2&=121_b,\\
  (1-i\sqrt{3})/2&=122_b,\\
  -1&=12102_b.
\end{align*}
One observes that all $b$-expansions of unit roots start with $1$.
Colouring Eisenstein integers with the first unit root occuring
during the computation
of the $b$-digit-expansion fails therefore for Eisenstein integers with
leading coefficient $2$ in their $b$-expansion. There are two natural
ways to deal with this problem: One can either use an additional seventh
colour for such Eisenstein integers or one can colour them with the same colour
as $1$. The second solution gives rise to the following picture:

[image]

The colour code is:

yellow for $1$ or if no unit root occurs during the computation of the
$b$-expansion,

green for $-1$,

red for $(1+i\sqrt{3})/2$,

blue for $-(1+i\sqrt{3})/2$,

white for $(-1+i\sqrt{3})/2$,

black for $(1-i\sqrt{3})/2$.

Comment: ‘Digits’ in $\{0, 1\}$ might perhaps be called bits ….

Comment: @LSpice I agree but 'bits' is very much related to base $2$. I avoided it for this (perhaps bad) reason.

Comment: Very nice, there should be material for a Monthly type paper here!

Comment: @ThomasSauvaget Thanks. For the moment this is only experimental. I would not be too surprised by something similar with Eisenstein integers.

Comment: By the way, the $-1,+i$ basis gives a curious bijection between $\mathbb N$ and Gaussian integers: interpret the 'digits' occuring in Gaussian integers as binary digits.

Comment: @RolandBacher So implicitly a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There's various related work out there, much of it recreational, about the connections between the "dragon curve" fractal and base $1 \pm i$:  I was able to find a bunch of stuff by googling "dragon curve" along with other relevant keywords.  See for instance: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~wgilbert/Research/MathIntel.pdf

But I didn't find anything addressing your question, and it looks like this area could use a good survey article!

Comment: @AlisonMiller : Thank you very much for your remark and the interesting reference.

Comment: Is the symmetry actually order 3 or is it order $\frac83$ because $\arg (-1 + i) = \frac38 (2\pi)$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor It is not an exact symmetry. There are however clearly three green regions. However, since there are also homotheties involved and since the green regions curl, you are perhaps right and your remark can perhaps made rigorous.